# Excel pivot table: how to make sure summing nulls returns null, not zero?

Tags: excel, null, pivot-table, nan

Does Excel even have the concept of null like in SQL (or NaN in Numpy, Matlab, etc.)?
Specifically, what I'm looking for is a way to make sure that a pivot table does not convert nulls to zero. For example:

- if the pivot sums 5 + null, then I want null returned, not 5
- if the pivot sums null + null, I want null returned, not zero

I have already cleansed my data so that zeros are zeros.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there at least a way to prevent empty cells from being treated as zeros? It doesn't make sense to me that, if you create a new spreadsheet and enter the formula =(k9=0) it returns True!!!!

Comment: Thank you. It is crazy that Excel is so widely used for data analysis despite being so poor. Compulsory SQL in school curricula, anyone? :)